# Not able to build the veins inet sub project of veins framework using inet

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I am using omnet++ 5.4.1,
veins latest from github ,
inet 4.0.0

When I am  building veins_inet project, the build fails showing the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Veins master @[bfdfc10](https://github.com/sommer/veins/commits/bfdfc10) is compatible with INET 4.0.0, but linking against INET 4.0.0 on Windows appears to be impossible. [Issue #379 of the INET framework](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues/379) is tracking this bug. You might have to wait for the next INET version.

A workaround is to build Veins on Linux or to download [Instant Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/).